# How can I change the icon above the user's name in the KDE lock screen?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5

I have changed the image, but would also like to customize that KDE wheel icon above the name of the user, without editing files or changing the global theme. How can I do it?

Kubuntu 23.04/KDE Plasma 5.27.4